# Using Where in a query with a function

Tags: sql, function, sql-server-2005, filtering

```
 SELECT col1, col2, dbo.myFunc(@param1, @param2, col1, col2) FROM theTable
```

How do I add a `WHERE` here to the result of the function `dbo.myFunc`, like `WHERE resultOfMyFunc > 10` for example?

Comment: You'll get more hits typically by tagging your question with the specific RDBMS you're using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the exact function call you use in the select in the query - the query optimizer should cache the value and use it in both places without re-evaluating the function (this is true for MSSQL, at least).

E.g.,

```
SELECT col1, col2, myFunc(@arg1, @arg2, col1, col2)
FROM myTable
WHERE myFunc(@arg1, @arg2, col1, col2) > 10
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to previous answers to cover another option...

If you don't want to repeat the function call in the WHERE clause (e.g. it takes a number of parameters and makes the query less readable in your eyes), you can do:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT col1, col2, dbo.myFunc(@param1, @param2, col1, col2) As funcResult
FROM theTable
) x
WHERE x.funcResult > 10
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
SELECT 
    col1, 
    col2, 
    dbo.myFunc(@param1, @param2, col1, col2) AS result
FROM 
    theTable
WHERE
    result > 10;
```

Best wishes,
Fabian

Comment: Doesn't, but I wish that would work, it looks way better than repeating the function and all.

Answer (score 1):

```
select col1, col2, dbo.myFunc(@param1, @param2, col1, col2)
from theTable
where dbo.myFunc(@param1, @param2, col1, col2) > 10
```

or (not sure if this second one will work across all SQL versions)

```
select col1, col2, dbo.myFunc(@param1, @param2, col1, col2) as funcVal
from theTable
where funcVal > 10
```

Comment: Yeah, that's been a source of continual frustration for me in using MSSQL.  I keep hoping they'll allow column aliases to be used in WHERE expressions, but alas, not yet (maybe this works in 2008? I'm still on 2005).

Comment: I just did a simple test on 2008 and it looks like you cannot use column aliases in the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 1):

For the love of god.
HAVING
  select col1, col2, dbo.myFunc(@param1, @param2, col1, col2)
from theTable
where dbo.myFunc(@param1, @param2, col1, col2) > 10

```
select col1, col2, dbo.myFunc(@param1, @param2, col1, col2) as calculated
FROM theTable
HAVING calculated > 10
```

Comment: Couldn't get it to work that way, could you please try to rewrite my function that way?

Comment: Still, doesn't work, it gives me the "Invailed column" for the column i did an AS for the alias.

Comment: not sure which sql flavour youre using.  
conditions on aggregate function results are usually on the having clause, not the where clause.
I'd recomment reading the appropiate documentation for the sql flavour your using

Answer (score 0):

You can just use it as you did in the SELECT:

```
WHERE
     dbo.myFunc(@param1, @param2, col1, col2) > 10
```